# Request SQL order by number 0 last

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal

How can i do a "ORDER BY" for 0 to be the last ?

```
$query->orderBy('price.field_selling_price_value');
```

Eg.

- 10
- 1000
- 2000
- 23999
- 0

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most databases you could do this with:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN field_selling_price_value = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, field_selling_price_value
```

In MySQL it's even simpler:

```
ORDER BY field_selling_price_value = 0, field_selling_price_value
```

Comment: For thoses who want to use Drupal way , i found we need to use it this way : 
$query->orderBy('price.field_selling_price_value = 0');

$query->orderBy('price.field_selling_price_value');

Answer (score 0):

MySQL Solution:

```
ORDER BY FIELD( price.field_selling_price_value, 0 ), price.field_selling_price_value
```

This condition sorts records in ascending order of `price.field_selling_price_value` and if found some records with value `0` for this column, they are placed in last.